# Pulling href src from iFrame onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to get the src of the current page loaded in the iFrame onLoad.

Basically, this is used for a two button nav. When img1 is clicked, a form is shown in the iFrame. when img2 is clicked, a new form is displayed and the link in the iFrame is changed.

I am trying to have the buttons highlighted depending on which page the iFrame is on.

I've tried using the location.window.href and src but, it only pulls up what initially has loaded in that frame and not what IS loaded in the frame.

```
<img id="img" src="pic1-off.png"></img>
<img id="img2" src="pic2-off.png"></img>
<iframe src="page1.php" name="frame1" id="frame1"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript>
document.getElementById("frame1").contentWindow.location.href

var img = document.getElementById('img');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
img.onmouseout = function () {
   img.src = 'pic1-off';
};

img.onmouseover = function () {
   img.src = 'pic1-on';
};
</script>
```

I expected the output to show what page the iFrame is currently on. Instead, I am only getting the output on what page was originally loaded in the iFrame.

Comment: At the bottom of my page, I have...

Current Page in Frame: <script>document.write(document.getElementById("frame1").src)</script>

Which shows only what was initially loaded in frame but not what IS loaded in frame.

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to do is when pic1 is selected, and that page is loaded, pic1 stays highlighted. when pic2 is selected and that page is loaded, pic2 stays highlighted.